# pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting to write into MySQL Table that was created using phpMyAdmin. I keep recieving the same error.
This is my code:

```
import pymysql

    connection=pymysql.connect(user='root',password='', host='localhost',database='ProjDB')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO 'userdata' ('FName','LName','UserName','Pword') VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('XXXX','XXX','XXXX','XXXX'))
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: What is the value of `sql` after you set it and before the cursor.execute line?

Answer (score 0):

The following line your code has some errors:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO 'userdata' ('FName','LName','UserName','Pword') VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

- Your table name has single quote added to it. sql treats it as a string instead of table name.
- The column names also are facing the same issue.
- The values should be enclosed in single quotes as when formatting it via string the values are placed exactly as the string is without single quotes.

example to explain it more clearly:
your current code formats the VALUES as :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO 'userdata' ('FName','LName','UserName','Pword') VALUES ( XXXX, XXX, XXXX, XXXX)"
```

But your columns are of type varchar so they should be enclosed in single quotes.

change that query by removing the single quotes from table name and column names and add single quotes to the values.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (FName,LName,UserName,Pword) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
cursor.execute(sql % ('XXXX','XXX','XXXX','XXXX'))
```

The Final formatted sql query will look like

```
INSERT INTO userdata (FName,LName,UserName,Pword) VALUES ('XXXX','XXX','XXXX','XXXX')
```